# SQL to get TOP rows of a distinct group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following setup:

```
ID    |    email_ID    |    email    |    priority
---------------------------------------------------
1       1                1@1.com       2
2       1                2@1.com       2
3       1                3@1.com       2
4       2                1@2.com       1
5       2                2@2.com       1
6       3                1@3.com       1
7       4                1@4.com       1
```

I want to be able to say get me the TOP 1000 rows but my results only contain one `email_ID` and be output in `priority` **ascending** order.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
select * from Table where email_ID in (select top 1 email_ID from Table group by email_ID)
```

..but I obviously haven't covered the order by `priority`. It's when I add this to the equation I get stumped.

so, on the first call I would get

```
 ID    |    email_ID    |    email    |    priority
---------------------------------------------------
4       2                1@2.com       1
5       2                2@2.com       1
```

second call:

```
ID    |    email_ID    |    email    |    priority
---------------------------------------------------
6       3                1@3.com       1
```

third:

```
ID    |    email_ID    |    email    |    priority
---------------------------------------------------
7       4                1@4.com       1
```

fourth:

```
ID    |    email_ID    |    email    |    priority
---------------------------------------------------
1       1                1@1.com       2
2       1                2@1.com       2
3       1                3@1.com       2
```

I want to get batches of up to 1000 at a time but each batch should be a unique `mail_ID` and the batches should come out in `priority` order (asc)

Comment: Could you please show us your expected output ?

Comment: Can you somehow rephrase what exactly you're trying to achieve? Your question is not quite clear.

Comment: more detail added. hope that helps !

Comment: @scgough, doesn't help. Unclear again. Why are you showing 4 distinct results? Do you think one and the same query can return different results when executed several times?

Comment: SQL Server does not guarantee **any** sort order without an `order by` in the query itself. You don't use `order by` in any of your queries, so it's no surprise to me that you aren't getting the results you want. Related note, using `TOP` without `order by` will also yield unpredictable, non-guaranteed results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the input. I think this was a case of couldn't see the wood for the trees!

I was having a think and the following would ensure the items came out in the desired order:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 t.* FROM [Table] t WHERE t.email_id IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 t2.email_id FROM [Table] t2 ORDER BY t2.priority
)
```

My table would be processed (up to) 1000 records at a time grouping results by `email_id` in the `priority` order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this with a windowing function if I understand the question correctly.

```
-- Your sample data
CREATE TABLE dbo.[table]
(
   ID INT,
   email_id INT,
   email CHAR(7),
   PRIORITY INT
)


INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (1,1,'1@1.com',2)
INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (2,1,'2@1.com',2)
INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (3,1,'3@1.com',2)
INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (4,2,'1@2.com',1)
INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (5,2,'2@2.com',1)
INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (6,3,'1@3.com',1)
INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (7,4,'1@4.com',1)


SELECT
  ID,
  Email_id,
  email,
  priority
FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email_id ORDER BY PRIORITY ASC) AS RowNum FROM dbo.[table]) TableA
WHERE RowNum <= 1000
ORDER BY Priority ASC, ID ASC
```

Comment: its ordering correctly but i want to only bring out a batch of a single mail_id per call. the idea is that i build a recipient list to send using the `mail_id` then move onto the next recipient list for the next `mail_id`

Comment: It sound to me like you may need a cursor to loop, get 1 email_id, send an email etc.

Answer (score 0):

---

*EDIT: I read the question one more time and a comment on another answer gave me a different insight into what you want. This last query will give you 1000 batches of `email_ID`s ordered by priority.*

```
select * from T where email_ID in (
    select top 1000
        email_ID, min(priority) as priority
    from T
    group by email_ID
    order by min(priority)
)
```

**Original answer follows:**

I'm thinking you want something like this. But do you need `ID` in the results too?

```
select top 1000
    email_ID, min(email) as email, min(priority) as priority
from T
group by email_ID
order by min(priority)
```

If you do then perhaps this will work:

```
select top 1000
    (
        select min(ID) from T t2
        where t2.email_ID = t.email_ID and t2.priority = t1.priority
    ) as ID,
    email_ID, min(email) as email, min(priority) as priority
from T t
group by email_ID
order by min(priority)
```

It's not clear to me whether you can have ties, that is multiple rows with the same email and priority. So I grabbed the minimum ID for that case.

Also if you can't have emails with distinct priorities then it would be easier to just return `min(ID)` without the subquery:

```
select top 1000
    min(ID) as ID, email_ID, min(email) as email, min(priority) as priority
from T
group by email_ID
order by min(priority)
```

I looked back at your questions and now see that `email`s across the same `email_ID` are not identical. I still suspect that grabbing `min(ID)` and `min(email)` will pull both values from the same row in your case but that would not be true in general. So I think the most generic approach is down this road:

```
select
    ID, email_ID,
    (
        select min(email) from T te
        where te.ID = tmin2.ID
    ) as email,
    priority
from (
    select
        min(ID) as ID,
        email_ID,
        min(t.priority) as priority as /* dummy aggregate */
    from 
        T t inner join
        (
            select top 1000 email_ID, min(priority) as priority
            from T
            group by email_ID
            order by priority
        ) tmin
            on tmin.email_ID = t.email_ID and tmin.priority = t.priority
    group by t.email_ID
) tmin2
```

Does your edition of SQL Server have `first_value()`?

Perhaps at this point you're confused: unfortunately you'll have to provide more info to sort some of this mess out.